time.perf_counter() or time.perf_counter_ns() giving weird and incorrect values
I have written this simple while I was working with multi-processing.
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
import time

def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while count < num:
        count += 1

def main():
    print(cpu_count())

  
    a = Process(target=counter, args=(250000000,))
    b = Process(target=counter, args=(250000000,))
    c = Process(target=counter, args=(250000000,))
    d = Process(target=counter, args=(250000000,))
    
    a.start()
    b.start()
    c.start()
    d.start()

    a.join()
    b.join()
    c.join()
    d.join()

    
    print("Finished in:", time.perf_counter(), "seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Well, everything in my code was going perfectly, except the time.perf_counter() giving like 7000 seconds for a program which barely even took 2-3 seconds. I tried using the time.perf_counter_ns()but it didn't work out as I expected. Firstly, it gave me values in scientific form and when I converted nanoseconds to seconds it still gave me the same result as earlier. And rather than those, I have tried using the timeit module priniting timeit.timeit(), and it literally gave me values like 0.0143249234 for a program which took more than 2 seconds. And when I print cpu_cores instead of showing how many cores my pc has it really gave me this <bound method BaseContext.cpu_count of <multiprocessing.context.DefaultContext object at 0x000001B68DDCD1C0>>.

[Edit] and paste code as text not an image so answerers won’t have to retype it (and most won’t)
